# Solve the differential equation $2xy''+y'+xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation:

$$2xy''+y'+xy=0$$

My try:

we can write it as:

$$xy''+y'=-x(y''+y)$$

$\implies$

$$d(xy')=-x(y''+y)$$

So we get

$$\frac{d(xy')}{xy'}=-\frac{y''}{y'}-\frac{y}{y'}$$

Integrating we get:

$$\ln|xy'|+\ln|y'|=\int \frac{-y}{y'}dx$$

How to proceed here?

Answer (score 2):

$$y''+\frac{1}{2x}y'+\frac12 y=0$$
This is an ODE of Bessel kind. A generalized form is given Eq.$(6)$ in : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

The change of variables $y=x^\alpha F(X)$ and $X=\beta x^\gamma$ reduces to a Bessel ODE on standard form, where $F$ is the unknown. The solution is $F=c_1J_{\nu}(X)+c_2Y_{\nu}(X)$

$J$ and $Y$ are the Bessel functions of the first and second kind. The final solution is :

$$y=c_1x^{\alpha}J_{\nu}(\beta x^\gamma)+c_2x^{\alpha}Y_{\nu}(\beta x^\gamma)$$

With the parameters : $\quad\alpha=\frac14\quad;\quad \gamma=1\quad;\quad \beta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\quad;\quad \nu=\frac14$